# Sql Server Replace function

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run the following statement but it is not working as expected.

It is meant to take the subquery value and remove it from the comment field (replace with empty string).

I have checked that the sub query returns the right value that I expect but the replace function isn't working as I would expect. Would anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

```
update contacts set comment = 
replace(comment,
   (select 'Specialty: ' + a.categoryname
    from contacts c
    join categories a
    on c.categorycode = a.categorycode
    where contacts.contactid = c.contactid)
, '')
```

Comment: Is it possible there are duplicate values in `Categories.CategoryCode`?

Comment: What error are you receiving? Are you sure you can fetch a record set and `UPDATE` it at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do i guess

```
update contacts 
set    comment = replace(comment,'Speciality :' + categories.categoryname,'')
from   contacts inner join categories 
on     contacts.categorycode=categories.categorycode
and    contacts.contactid=categories.contactid
```

[in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6dc7/3)

Comment: Why is the contacts table twice in the range table? (once on the left-hand size of `=` and once on the right, in the **uncorrelated** subquery)

Comment: that is how update join works :) i did not use alias here for contacts table

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It didn't require the last line but i commented that out and it still didn't work as I would expect. Very puzzling.

Comment: that works i tried that in sqlfiddle,may be it is related to space or syntax

Comment: Thanks for your help. I needed to rtrim(categories.categoryname)

Comment: i thought so, glad that helped

Answer (score 0):

This is the Replace function:

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

Are you sure the `string_pattern` matches something in the `string_expression` ?

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to the same information

Comment: Hi, Yes i've checked the sub query returns what I would expect.

Comment: Could you show an example(data) of an comment being updated and the return from the sub-query ?